# Create a teams meeting with Graph API where users can bypass the lobby

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to receive a Microsoft teams meeting link from Graph API using the "/users/${userId}/calendar/events" endpoint. This is my current request body:

```
  subject: "Test Meeting",
  start: {
    dateTime: startTime,
    timeZone: "UTC",
  },
  end: {
    dateTime: endTime,
    timeZone: "UTC",
  },
  isOnlineMeeting: true,
```

What property should I add to allow participants to join without the lobby approve?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should include online meeting resource properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0#json-representation

```
{
   ...
   "onlineMeeting": {
      "lobbyBypassSettings": { "scope": "everyone", "isDialInBypassEnabled": false }
   }
   ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

Well, the above seems to be logical but it appears **not** to be **supported** that way.

With Calendar API `onlineMeetingInfo` resource is used, not `onlineMeeting`. And `lobbyBypassSettings` is a property of `onlineMeeting`.
So it seems to be not even possible to create Event your way and update onlineMeeting with lobby settings or link Event with Online Meeting. If it's mandatory to bypass lobby, consider API for online meetings.

Here's some info on differences of these 2 approaches

[considerations for online meeting from ms365 community](https://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dv_OPxD7E6o) (9:50 for lobby)

[choose-online-meeting-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/choose-online-meeting-api)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still gives me an error saying: " "body": "{\"code\":\"UnableToDeserializePostBody\",\"message\":\"were unable to deserialize \"}""

Comment: the error says something wrong with JSON body. validate it with http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: also, for meetings this error can be caused by wrong datetime format

Comment: No, it is definitely the new property because if I delete it, than it runs perfectly fine

Comment: can you share the full json you post?

Comment: Sure, const newMeeting = `/users/${userId}/calendar/events`;

    const event = {
      subject: "Customer Service Meeting",
      start: {
        dateTime: "2023-01-09T22:00:00",
        timeZone: "UTC",
      },
      end: {
        dateTime: "2023-01-09T23:00:00",
        timeZone: "UTC",
      },
      isOnlineMeeting: true,
      onlineMeeting: {
        lobbyBypassSettings: {
          scope: "everyone",
          isDialInBypassEnabled: false,
        },
      },
    };

    const newEvent = await appGraphClient.api(newMeeting).post(event);

Comment: Well, I've checked more and it's not working that way, unfortunately. I've updated my answer, please check.